# PHP mysqli empty array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have a question about my code. When i try to fill my html with my fetched array i only get blank spaces instead of the actual results. Can anyone tell me why ?

```
<?php
require_once("php/loader.inc.php");
include("php/header.php");
include("php/userpanel.php");
$gebruiker = $_SESSION['user'];
?>


<div class="large-8 columns">
<div class="row">  


<?php
$query = "
SELECT
   items.naam,
   items.prijs,
   items.image_url
FROM inventory
JOIN items
 ON items.id = inventory.item_id
WHERE
 gebruiker_id = ?
";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt-> bind_param('i', $gebruiker->id);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $user_items[] = $row;

   echo '<div class="large-3 small-4 columns">
<img src="'. $user_items['image_url'] .'">
<div class="panel">
    <h6>'. $user_items['naam'] .'</h6>
<h6 class="subheader">'. $user_items['prijs'] .'</h6>
</div>
</div>'; 

}
?>
```

By the way, when i try `print_r($user_items);` it gives me the expected result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this line `$user_items[] = $row;` you can use `$row` directly

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{        
   echo '<div class="large-3 small-4 columns">
  <img src="'. $row['image_url'] .'">
  <div class="panel">
    <h6>'. $row['naam'] .'</h6>
    <h6 class="subheader">'. $row['prijs'] .'</h6>
  </div>
  </div>';     
}
```

Comment: Haha yes i will as soon as the timer restriction is off the button :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to change this:

```
$user_items[] = $row;
```

to this:

```
$user_items = $row;
```

Otherwise your indexes are 1 dimension 'deeper'

**As an example:**

```
$row = array("image_url" => "xy");
```

after this line:

```
$user_items[] = $row;
```

You can't access it with:

```
echo $user_items["image_url"];  //Wrong
```

you would have to do this:

```
echo $user_items[0]["image_url"];  //works
```